# Difference between `svn add` and `svn commit` in Apache Subversion

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

What is the difference between Add and Commit in SVN?

I understand that Add adds a new file to SVN and Commit updates any changes done for an already existing file in the SVN

My question is, do I need to do a Commit after adding new files using Add?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a great chapter in SVNBook which describes basic workflow with Subversion: [SVNBook | Basic Work Cycle](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/tour/cycle/). The chapter explains, that `svn add` et all are commands related to *making changes* and `svn commit` is a command which *publishes these changes* to a repository as a new revision.

- [`svn add`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svn/c/add/) adds an item (file or directory) to a local working copy. `svn add` is a local operation and does not contact server. No changes made to a repository when you run `svn add`. It simply *schedules* and item to be committed to a repository next time your run `svn commit`.
- [`svn commit`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svn/c/commit/) commits changes to a repository.

Answer (score -3):

SVN Add:

When you are creating a new file or directory, you need to tell the SVN server about it. This command does that.

SVN Commit:

This command recursively sends your changes to the SVN server. It will commit changed files, added files, and deleted files. Note that you can commit a change to an individual file or changes to files in a specific directory path by adding the name of the file/directory to the end of the command.

Go [here](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/edguide/chapter03.html#ch03-add) for an SVN Command guide.

Comment: `svn add` doesn't tell the server anything. It flags the item as added in your **working copy**, but that doesn't communicate anything to the server - that happens when you `commit`.